# Installing applications with larger size on S DUOS

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-duos

I am using Galaxy-S-Duos 
Android 4.0
Internal memory 1.8 GB !

What if I want to install application like Modern Combat-4 (1.9 GB)

These applications require to be installed in phone memory for their 1st run.
After that the can be moved to SD card..

Is it possible to install them directly to SD card?

Answer (score 2):

Installing apps from Google Play will first download the `.apk` file to `/data/local`, which is in the device's internal memory – so you're already lost before the installation itself even had begun. And that's only the first hurdle to be taken:

Though one could set the "[default installation location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html)" (using `adb set-install-location`, see [adb help](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)), the app must explicitly support to be installed on anything other than internal storage. If it does not support this, it cannot be installed there (though you might be able to move it there *lateron* with some special apps enforcing it).

Answer (score 0):

use foldermount to mount the specific data and obb folder to mount it as external storage.You will need root for this.Alternatively,you can use link2sd and/or gltosd for the same.I have nova 3 installed that way

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for helping other visitors. This answer could be a lot more helpful if you described the process in more detail. Assume the questioner doesn't know what foldermount is or how to find the data and obb folders.